Warning: pack(): Type H: not enough characters in string in
I'm trying to change the php code to be compatible with php 8.2.12 from php 6.0.0-dev. The code deals with hexadecimal so I'm a little confused with the output.
Here's an example of the result of the code that came out, php 8.2.12
i 0
i 0
H8 0 << questionable result

Warning: pack(): Type H: not enough characters in string in C:\xampp\htdocs\services\parser\include.php on line 683
H8 16000000
H8 0d000000

Previously in the php 6.0.0-dev version the result was
i 0
i 0
i 0 << questionable result
H8 16000000
H8 0d000000

So the value of format i 0 before H8 16000000 in php 8.2.12 is changed to H8 0 which makes an error "Warning: pack(): Type H: not enough characters in string in C:\xampp\htdocs\parser\include.php on line 683"
Can anyone help with this problem? Here is the complete code of the parser function
function parser($output, $input, $indexing, $blockheader)
{
    global $typearr, $stop_error_msg;
    $filearray = file($input, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $filesize = sizeof($filearray);
    $struct = explode("\t", trim($filearray[0]));
    $col_names = explode("\t", trim($filearray[1]));
    if ($blockheader == 1)
    {
        // Define or replace strsize() function
        // $block = strsize($struct);
        $block = count($struct); // Example replacement
        if ($indexing == 1)
            $block += 4;
        $filesize_bin = pack("i", ($filesize - 2));
        fwrite($output, $filesize_bin);
        $blockbin = pack("i", $block);
        fwrite($output, $blockbin);
    }
    for ($i = 2; $i < $filesize; $i++)
    {
        $store = 0;
        $temporary = explode("\t", trim($filearray[$i]));
        if ($indexing == 1)
            fwrite($output, pack("i", $i - 2));
        for ($st = 0; $st < count($struct) - 1; $st++)
        {
            if ($temporary[$st] == '')
            {
                $stop_error_msg .= "<br>Empty cell. Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                return false;
            }

            if (stristr($struct[$st], 'string[') !== false)
            {
                preg_match("/^(string\[)?([\d]+)/", $struct[$st], $str_ret);
                if (strlen($temporary[$st]) >= $str_ret[2])
                {
                    $temporary[$st] = substr($temporary[$st], 0, $str_ret[2] - 1);
                    echo "<br>Warning! Text overflow. Tail of string had been cut: ROW:".($i+1)." COLUMN:".($st+1)." NAME:".$col_names[$st]." DATA:'".$temporary[$st]. "' SIZE:". $str_ret[2];
                }
                //if(strlen($temporary[$st]) >= 255 && stristr($input, 'Desc') !== false)
               // {
               //     echo "<br>Warning! Exceeded max length of 255 symbols at item description. Tail of string wont be shown in game: ROW:".($i+1)." COLUMN:".($st+1)." NAME:".$col_names[$st]." DATA:'".$temporary[$st]. "' SIZE:". $str_ret[2];
                    //$temporary[$st] = substr($temporary[$st], 0, 254);
               // }
                $resulthex = pack("a".$str_ret[2], trim(str_replace("\x22\x22\x22\x22", "\x22\x22", $temporary[$st]), "\x22"));
                fwrite($output, $resulthex);
                continue;
            }
            $type = $typearr[$struct[$st]]['type'];
            switch($type)
            {
                case "xeh":
                    $resulthex = xeh($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "xeh64":
                    $resulthex = xeh64($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "clcode":
                    $resulthex = clcode($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "exclcode":
                    if(($resulthex = exclcode($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "ccode":
                    $resulthex = ccode($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "f":
                case "d":
                    $trans = array("," => ".");
                    $resulthex = pack($type, strtr("".$temporary[$st]."", $trans));
                    break;
                case "bulltype":
                    if(($resulthex = bulltype($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "bttype":
                    if(($resulthex = bttype($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "effbttype":
                    if(($resulthex = effbttype($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "stb":
                    if(($resulthex = stb($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "stb4":
                    if(($resulthex = stb4($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "stb12":
                    if(($resulthex = stb12($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "stb16":
                    if(($resulthex = stb16($temporary[$st])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    break;
                case "res":
                    $resulthex = resource($temporary[0]);
                    break;
                case "qitid":
                    $resulthex = qitid($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "lqitem":
                    $resulthex = lqitem($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "store":
                    if(($resulthex = store($temporary[$st], $store, $temporary[10])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    $store++;
                    break;
                case "qcode":
                    $resulthex = qcode($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "spcode":
                    $resulthex = spcode($temporary[$st]);
                    break;
                case "text":
                    $len = strlen($temporary[$st]);
                    $len = $len + 1;
                    $resulthex=pack("a".$len, $temporary[$st]);
                    $plen=pack("i", $len);
                    fwrite($output, $plen);
                    break;
                case "param":
                    if(($resulthex = param($temporary[$st], $temporary[$st+1])) === false)
                    {
                        $stop_error_msg .= " Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                        return false;
                    }
                    $st++;
                    break;
                default:
                    echo $type." ".$temporary[$st]."<br>";
                    $resulthex = pack($type, $temporary[$st]); # error indication is in this script
            }
            if(!empty($err_arr) && isset($err_arr['message']) && stripos($err_arr['message'], 'function.date') !== false) {
                $stop_error_msg .= "<br>Pack error. Probably mistake at excel file:<br>ROW:".($i+1)."<br>COLUMN:".($st+1)."<br>NAME:".$col_names[$st]."<br>DATA:".$temporary[$st];
                return false;
            }
            fwrite($output, $resulthex);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

I just tried to change the value of the $type variable to fix for the i format, but the result is still messy
default:
   echo "i" ".$temporary[$st]."<br>";
   $resulthex = pack("i", $temporary[$st]); # error indication is in this script

i0
i0
i0 << questionable result
i16000000 << changed to i format
i0d000000 << changed to i format

Do I need to add a new function to handle H8 format and make a separate case instead of default?

from php 6.0.0-dev - whateevr that means: can you reduce the code to a minimal example that helps others to understand it? The code you've shared can't do anything, as parser is not called anywhere

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

@NicoHaase I'm sorry sir, I will try to minimize my code. And also I forgot that the parser() function is called from another file.
